# How to transform this limit expression as a limit of $e$

Tags: calculus

I have the following expression:

$\displaystyle\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\dfrac{x+2}{\:x-6}\right)^\left(\dfrac{x}{\:4}\right)$

I'm studying Calculus I and our lector has shown us ways of transforming such limits to:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{\:x}\right)^x = e$

The way [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bx%2B2%7D%7B%20x-6%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B4%7D%7D) calculator solves it is not immediately clear to me, is there any other way to find the above limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\left(\frac{x+2}{x-6}\right)^{\frac x 4}=\left(\frac{x-6+8}{x-6}\right)^{\frac x 4}=\left(1+\frac{8}{x-6}\right)^{\frac x 4}$$

then we can manipulate further in order to use the standard limit.

Refer to the related

- [Calculating a limit with trignonometeric and quadratic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2651471/505767)

Comment: I've already reached that, the problem is I don't know what to do next. I tried adding and subtracting 6/4 from the power, but it didn't quite work out...

Comment: @PowerUser Use that $A^n=(A^m)^{\frac n m}$.

Comment: I solved it. What I used was A^(n/m) = (A^n)^(1/m) and got e^(8/4) = e^2. Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm not used to MathJax… Seeing as this is the oldest answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @PowerUser You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @PowerUser Recall that as ana alternative we can also use that $$f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{g(x) \log (f(x))}$$ to obtain teh same result by standard limit  $$t \to 0 \quad \frac{\log (1+t)}t \to 1$$

Answer (score 1):

You may proceed as follows:

- Set $y = x-6$
  $$\left(\frac{x+2}{x-6} \right)^{\frac{x}{4}} = \left(1 +\frac{8}{y} \right)^{\frac{y+6}{4}} = \left(1 +\frac{2}{\frac{y}{4}} \right)^{\frac{y}{4}}\cdot \left(1 +\frac{8}{y} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \stackrel{y \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}e^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\dfrac{x+2}{\:x-6}\right)^\left(\dfrac{x}{\:4}\right)=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\dfrac{1+\dfrac2x}{1-\dfrac6x}\right)^\left(\dfrac{x}{\:4}\right)=\dfrac{\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac2x\right)^{x/2}\right)^{1/2}}{\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac6x\right)^{-x/6}\right)^{-3/2}}=\dfrac{e^{1/2}}{e^{-3/2}}=?$

Answer (score 0):

If you divide $x+2$ by $x-6$ the quotient is $1$ and the remainder is $8$, so the limit becomes
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{8}{x-6}\right)^{x/4}$$

Now, substitute $x/4$ by
$$\frac{x-6}8\cdot\frac{8}{x-6}\cdot\frac x4$$
to get

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{\dfrac{x-6}8}\right)^{\dfrac{x-6}8}\right]^{\dfrac{8x}{4(x-6)}}$$