# How to use $\lesssim$ when using exponents

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I found the explanation for the $\lesssim$ in this question:

[What does a tilde underneath an inequality mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/804573/571776)

My problem is of the following nature:

$g_t(y)$ is a stochastic function and $M_t$ some stochastic process, where $t\in[0,T]$ is the time parameter. Then there is the growth condition
\begin{align*}
|g_t(y)|\lesssim 1+|y|+|M_t|.
\end{align*}
Now, when squaring $g_t(y)$ I wonder, whether the growth condition expands to
\begin{align*}
|g_t(y)|^2\lesssim 1+|y|^2+|M_t|^2 \text{ or }\\
|g_t(y)|^2 \lesssim (1+|y|+|M_t|)^2.
\end{align*}

The reason for my question is, that I found an inequation, where they used the first inequation. This triggered the thought, that maybe $g_t(y)$'s growth is determined in the different parameters independently and thus one can square them individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options are valid, because for any non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$, we have
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\le(a+b+c)^2\le 3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
So each of $1+|y|^2+|M_t|^2$ and $(1+|y|+|M_t|)^2$ is bounded by a constant multiple of the other.